# insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I have looked at a bunch of similar posts and none seem to give me the answer I need. When I try to add data to a model via the Django Admin site, it gives me this error:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/api/appuser/
insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

When I looked at my database, the table `auth_user` did only have one entry with `user_id 1`. So it does make sense that the error is thrown. However, I am not sure why it is even looking at the `auth_user` table in the first place because I have another table called `api_appuser` where my actual users are stored. In this table, there is a `user` with `id` 2. So, can anyone help me figure out why this error is being thrown and why `admin.py` is looking at the `auth_user` table in the first place? Thanks! Also, I am using Postgres as my database if that matters.

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation: insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) is not present in table "auth_user".


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 683, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1983, in changelist_view
    response = self.response_action(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1588, in response_action
    response = func(self, request, queryset)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/actions.py", line 50, in delete_selected
    modeladmin.log_deletion(request, obj, obj_display)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 952, in log_deletion
    return LogEntry.objects.log_action(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/models.py", line 38, in log_action
    return self.model.objects.create(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 514, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 857, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1000, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1041, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1434, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1621, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/jhcscomputer1/.local/share/virtualenvs/senior_project-hOu14Mps/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) is not present in table "auth_user".
```

Comment: Nobody answered?